# Triggering application on Compute engine VM from Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I would like to trigger a python script on Cloud runtime from Cloud function. I am able to start the Cloud VM from cloud function using client library ,however i am not able to run 'gcloud ssh' command from cloud function.

Is there a way to achieve this? One option is to use the python script as the VM Start up script but I am trying not to do that .

Comment: did you add the this firewall rule ?
`gcloud compute firewall-rules create --network=YOURNETWORK default-allow-ssh --allow=tcp:22 `
if yes , can you plz add the error that you're getting ?

Comment: What's  your use case? Why do you need to use a VM and to run a script on that VM?

Comment: I want to trigger a Python application on VM. As the application takes around 1.5 hours to complete. i can't run the whole thing on Cloud run.